# `git pull` and `git fetch` do not interpret arguments consistently: (design) bug or (design) feature?

Tags: git

<sub>This question is more "theoretical" than the typical SO question, so I feel a certain justification is in order.  One of the difficulties I have with `git` is that I find myself constantly doing things that seem to me that they "should work", but don't.  This remains true even after using `git` pretty much daily for the last 10 months or so, and having studied it more intensively than pretty much any other software tool that I use for work.  This means that, deep down, `git` simply does not make sense to me.  The purpose of this question, therefore, is only ***to make sense of*** `git`, and hopefully reduce the mismatch between what I think "should work", and what actually does.  (BTW, "read the docs" is not the solution; something can be documented in minute detail and still make no sense.)</sub>

This question is a follow-up to an earlier one I asked: [How to decompose git pull <REMOTE> <BRANCH> into a fetch + merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484033).  In particular, I recommend running the example script given in that question, and examining its output.

A `git pull` command is supposed to be a combination of a `git fetch` and a `git merge`.

Therefore I am puzzled by the fact that, if `<BRANCHNAME>` is the current branch, then running

```
git pull --no-edit <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

updates the tracking branch `<REMOTENAME>/<BRANCHNAME>`<sup>1</sup>, whereas

```
git fetch <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

leaves `<REMOTENAME>/<BRANCHNAME>` unchanged, and therefore attempting to merge it with `<BRANCHNAME>` is normally a no-op.

Is there any way to make sense of this apparent inconsistency?  Alternatively, why doesn't `git fetch <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>` fail outright, or at least give a warning?  Is what it does a common use-case that's worth preserving?

In short, is this apparent inconsistency a *bug* in the design of the `git` interface, or is it a *feature*, and if the latter is the case, how is it a feature?

EDIT: Just to clarify: this question *is agnostic*/*unconcerned* with the issue of how well the behavior described above agrees with its documentation.  What this question is trying to ascertain is whether the difference in the conventions followed by `git pull` and `git fetch` when interpreting their arguments is ***a (design) bug or a (design) feature.***

<sub><sup>1</sup>Plus it carries out any necessary merge between `<BRANCHNAME>` and this updated `<REMOTENAME>/<BRANCHNAME>`, or at least it gets this merge started.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it.

#### The refspecs

First, let's debunk what the thing called "refspec" is, as this will be needed down the road.

The refspec stands for "reference specification". A reference is something pointing to a commit or to another reference. A branch is a reference, a tag is a reference; `HEAD` is a special (the so-called "symbolic") reference. Let's ignore the distinction between various kind of references at the moment.

It's common to call references just "refs" for short.

A refspec has the form:

```
[+]source[:destination]
```

- `source` designates the reference to take the series of commits from.
- `destination`, if specified, designates a reference to *update* with the series of commits taken from `source`.
- A plus sign, if included, *forces* updating to happen even if the line of commits pointed to by `destination` is not *completely contained* in the line of commits pointed to by `source`.

The refspecs are used for both fetching and pushing, and the meaning of source and destination refs is reversed in these cases, obviously: when we fetch, the source refs are in the remote repo, and when we push, the source refs are in our local repo.

With plain Git (I mean its reference implementation), refs are just files whose names are relative to the root of their repository (for normal repositories this is the ".git" directory, for bare repositories this is the repository root directory).

Some references, like `HEAD` (or `ORIG_HEAD` or `MERGE_HEAD` or `FETCH_HEAD`) are located right in the root of the repository while some others, like branches and tags and remote branches are located in the directory named "refs" and there they are further sorted under their respective subdirectories:

- Branches are in the "refs/heads" subdirectory.
- Tags are in "refs/tags".
- Remote branches are in "refs/remotes/<remote>" directory of their appropriate remote.
- Notes are in "refs/notes".
- ...

Hence a full name of the ref representing a branch named "master" is indeed "refs/heads/master", and a remote branch named "foo" fetched from a named remote repository "origin" is "refs/remotes/origin/foo".

Git uses smart lookup mechanism to allow you to abbreviate ref names most of the time, but full (or "fuller") names might be used when there is any ambiguity of just when you want to be strict. The gory details are in [the `git rev-parse` manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).

(These explanations about full ref names are needed to understand how *simple* calls to `git fetch` work which are explained below.)

#### Fetching

Now back to fetching.

`git fetch` basically several modes of operation depending on what arguments you supplied to it:

- `git fetch <git_url>` takes whatever the ref `HEAD` points to in the remote repository accessed via `<git_url>`, fetches its history and writes the SHA-1 name of its tip commit to the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file.

  In a bare repository `HEAD` typically points at the branch named "master" (though this might be changed). In a non-bare (normal) repository `HEAD` obviously points at what's currently checked out to the work tree.
- `git fetch <git_url> <refspec> ...` uses the specified refspecs to fetch from the remote repository (instead of `HEAD`), and — for those refspecs which include the "destination" part, it also tries to update those local refs with the fetched history. The SHA-1 names of each fetched refspec is written to the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file.

  To demonstrate:

  ```
  git fetch git://server/repo.git master devel test
  From git://server/repo.git
   * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   * branch            devel      -> FETCH_HEAD
   * branch            test       -> FETCH_HEAD
  ```

  Note that while the commits were fetched, no local refs were updated.

  Now let's do it in a more involved way:

  ```
  git fetch git://server/repo.git master devel:foo test:bar
  From git://server/repo.git
   * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   * [new branch]      devel      -> foo
   * [new branch]      test       -> bar
  ```

  As you can see, `git fetch` created two local branches, "foo" and "bar" while "master" was just fetched but was not used to create anything in our local repo.  SHA-1 names of all three remote refs still end up in the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file.
- `git fetch <remote> <refspec> ...` — with `<remote>` being a named remote repository configured using `git remote add` or automatically created by `git clone` — behaves exactly like the forms with explicit `<git_url>` but `git fetch` obtains the url to use from the configuration of that named remote.
- `git fetch <remote>` fetches *all* the branches from that remote and tries to update (or create, if they do not exist) the so-called *remote branches* for that remote.

  This is crucial to understand that this course of operation is not magic. When you add a named remote (or `git clone` creates one for you), Git adds to your repository configuration several variables describing that remote, and one of them will be the `remote.<name>.fetch` parameter which is a refspec *and* which is used if no refspecs are passed to `git fetch` directly (!).

  Now, for the remote named "origin" Git will create the parameter `remote.origin.fetch` set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. You can go to your local repo and see this for yourself:

  ```
  $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  ```
- "The most magic" is plain `git fetch` — it works like the call above just the remote is picked up automatically.

#### Pulling (fetching plus merging)

Pulling it defined as "fetch then merge what was fetched to the currently checked out branch".  The refspec(s) passed to `git pull` (or their lack thereof) are handed directly to `git fetch`, and hence all the rules described above apply.

Why `git pull <remote> <branch>` updates the matching remote branch while `git fetch   doesn't?

To understand this "mystery", it helps to keep in mind that Git employs certain convenient magic behind the scenes when it comes to remote branches and their *remote-tracking* branches (when yo do `git fetch origin` followed by `git branch foo origin/foo`, the "origin/foo" is a remote branch and "foo" is a remote-tracking branch, as it tracks a corresponding remote branch). Another point which you should keep in mind is that remote branches are there to capture the state of the corresponding branches in their remote repository at the time of the last fetch.

Now suppose you push a remote-tracking branch to the same-named branch in the remote repository (the most usual case). Let's say you did this:

```
$ git fetch origin
(this created the "origin/foo" branch)
$ git chekcout -b foo origin/foo
(this created a new local branch "foo" tracking "origin/foo")
$ git commit ...
$ git push origin foo
```

While pushing, Git notices that if you *would be fetching* to the matching remote branch *at the same time,* you'd get the same commits in it which were just pushed. So it goes on and makes "origin/foo" point to the same commit "foo" points to.

Now back to `git pull`... In your case, after `git pull` completed, Git noticed that you have just updated a remote-tracking branch with the commits obtained from a branch for which you have a remote branch locally, so it goes on and updates this remote branch because this is its last seen state.

Let's recap:

1. "origin/foo" is a remote branch which captures the state of a branch named "foo" in the remote repository "origin".
2. "foo" is a local branch which tracks "origin/foo".
3. You do

   ```
   git checkout foo
   git pull origin foo
   ```

   Git updates your "foo" branch as the result, but this implies "foo" now has at least one commit "origin/foo" would receive if you would just `git fetch origin` or `git push origin foo`, so Git proceeds and updates "origin/foo" as well.

That is, in my opinion, updating of the remote branch in your case happened not because `git fetch ...` was run but because a local remote-tracking branch got updated as the result of merging. Does it make sense now?

#### Further reading

I would recommend to just read the ".git/config" file in your repository to get the idea of how all this "remote stuff" is configured.

Answer (score 0):

The git-fetch man page says

> The ref names and their object names of fetched refs are stored in .git/FETCH_HEAD. This information is left for a later merge operation done by git merge.

Running `git fetch origin master` will store the result of the fetch in the `FETCH_HEAD` ref. You can merge it into your current branch with `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

The man page also says

> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source ref `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`.

You can tell git fetch to update the ref with `git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master`.