# Git: what exactly causes remote branches to update?

Tags: git, remote-branch

According to Pro Git (3.5):

```
[remote branches are] local branches that you can’t move; they’re moved     
automatically whenever you do any network communication.
```

However, this doesn't seem to be correct in practise. I've arrived at a situation where I get

```
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch-x' by 23 commits.
```

but I haven't actually done any commits, just fetched /pulled modifications that other people have pushed to origin.
If the statement of Pro Git was correct I would expect my remote branch to be the same as my local one, since every fetch or pull would be a communication with origin.

What are the exact operations that update the remote branches?

Comment: Try running `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`. Then run `git push` and rerun that command. Maybe that will clear things up for you.

Comment: Maybe somebody rewrote history on remote?

Comment: Try this...`clone` another instance of this repo and run `git status` on this newly cloned repo...let us know if it still gives you 23 commits message

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15503763/720999).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your issue might be rooted in a special twist `git pull` has in its semantics — let's cite the `git pull` manual:

> Some short-cut notations are also supported.
>   ...
>   A parameter <ref> without a colon is equivalent to <ref>: when pulling/fetching, so it merges <ref> into the current branch without storing the remote branch anywhere locally

This means that when you do

```
git pull
```

or

```
git pull origin
```

(which rely on the `branch.<name>.remote` and also `branch.<name>.merge` — in the latter case — configuration variables) then all the branches the remote repo has are fetched and the remote branches in your local repository are updated accordingly.

But when you do `git pull origin branch-x`, then the objects of the branch "branch-x" in the repo "origin" are fetched<sup>1</sup>, *no remote branch is updated in your local repo,* and then the fetched tip object is merged into the currently checked out branch.

So to fix your situation just run `git fetch origin` and have your remote branches updated.
You might want to consider reading [this blog post](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) to get a better idea of why `git pull` is not a precise equivalent to `git fetch` + `git merge` in all the possible cases.

Another way to fix the situation for the `origin/branch-x` remote branch is to do `git push origin branch-x` assuming your local `branch-x` is set to track `origin/branch-x` — this happens because when you push a tracking branch Git knows the receiving branch in the remote repo now looks exactly like the branch you've just pushed and so it's a sane thing to update the matching remote branch.
If you do not feel yourself comfortable with these concepts (remote branches vs tracking branches) start from reading [this part of The Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, actually only the objects which are missing in your local repository are fetched.

Comment: Thanks - this sounds like the likely explanation. I'll need to study the pull man page for a while to understand it. I suppose I was misinterpreting the Pro Git quote "automatically updated" to mean that the remote branches were always "automatically" moved to the same positions as in the remote repo, whereas the automation actually includes the possibility that they won't be moved at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like the book says, they're moved automatically whenever git does any network operations. So that would include `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git pull`.

> If the statement of Pro Git was correct I would expect my remote branch to be the same as my local one, since every fetch or pull would be a communication with origin.

I think you're a bit confused about what is meant by "moved automatically". When remote branches are moved, they are moved to reflect the current state of the remote repository. The remote repository itself isn't changed by `git fetch` or `git pull`, so the remote branches don't move either.

Try running `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` to see a nice graph of the current state of your repository. Note the position of `branch-x` and `origin/branch-x` in that graph. Then, run `git push` to push your changes up to the remote repository. Then run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` again; you'll see that `origin/branch-x` has moved. That's what is meant in the quote you referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may be confused, but not to the extent that I expect git fetch or git pull to modify the remote repository. As I understand it, the "remote branches" are part of my repository, and therefore *are* updated by git fetch or git pull - to make them match the equivalent branch on the remote - and that is what is meant by moved automatically. Nothing changes in the remote repo, just my local "remote branches". Please correct me if I'm wrong.